# 500 Internal server error after changing mysql query

Tags: php, codeigniter, internal-server-error

Yesterday I changed my database schema, and consequently a database query in my application, since then I have been receiving 500 Internal Server Errors. I do not think that the problem is the query, as I can run it from my model, and print the array from my controller. The problem seems to be when building the template.

Below is my code,

**MODEL**

```
public function searchCandidates($type=null, $gender=null, $age=null)
    {
        if($age != "0") {
            $age = implode(", %",$age);
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, 
                        `candidates`.`first_name`, 
                        `candidates`.`surname`, 
                        `candidates`.`DOB`, 
                        `candidates`.`gender`, 
                        `candidates`.`talent`, 
                        `candidates`.`location`, 
                        `candidates`.`availability`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_1`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_2`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_3`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_4`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_5`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_desc_1`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_desc_2`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_desc_3`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_desc_4`,
                        `candidates`.`youtube_showreel_desc_5`,
                        `candidates`.`date_created`,
                         DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y") - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, "%Y") - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "00-%m-%d") < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, "00-%m-%d")) as `age`,
                        `candidate_assets`.`url`, 
                        `candidate_assets`.`asset_size`
                FROM `candidates`
                LEFT JOIN `candidate_assets` ON `candidate_assets`.`candidates_candidate_id` = `candidates`.`candidate_id`
                WHERE `candidates`.`availability` = "yes"';
                //is there a certain criteria
                if($type != "0") { $sql .= 'AND `candidates`.`talent` = '.$type; }
                if($age != "0") { $sql .= 'AND `candidates`.`playing_age` LIKE "%'.$age.'%"';}
                if($gender != false){ $sql .= 'AND `candidates`.`gender` = '.$gender; }
                $sql .= ' GROUP BY `candidates`.`candidate_id`';

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        //die(print_r($query->result_array()));

        //die($this->db->last_query());
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$data['results'] = 

$this->candidates_model->searchCandidates($this->input->post('type'), $this->input->post('gender'), $this->input->post('age')); 
            $this->session->set_userdata('search', $data['results']);
            //die(print_r($this->session->userdata('search')));
            $this->template->build('search/results', $data);
```

The error in my error logs looks like this,

> [Fri Dec 09 10:28:49 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xxx] malformed
>   header from
>         script. Bad header=Bs%3A2%3A%2259%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%:   index.php, referer:  http://urbantalent.factoryagency.co.uk/search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that you are trying to put too many things into the ci_session cookie.
Some of the values there might not be encoded properly and don't look like a valid header. set-cookie HTTP header will then be wrong hence you get the "malformed header" error.
Start by limiting WHAT goes into this cookie. Perhaps disable/don't use it at all if you can (temporarily while you debug your code)

Then fix the dynamic SQL - you need space in front of each "AND"

.gender should probably also be wrapped in double quotes.

EDIT:
Yes, now I am even more convinced.
sico87 - This is live from your site (see below - sorry for a very long string).
The size of this cookie is close to 8K. There are certain limits on the size of HTTP headers. And from memory for Apache it is 8K.
So my best guess (yes, guess!) is that under certain circumstances you put more than 8K in the cookie and this request fails. The solution is to not use cookies to store/transfer large volumes of data.

```
ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22f80a32998134fc9d24ee7cf0ee41592a%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%2299.99.99.99%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A70%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28compatible%3B+MSIE+9.0%3B+Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%3B+Trident%2F5.0%29%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1323429638%3Bs%3A7%3A%22search1%22%3Ba%3A15%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2252%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22Eric%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22James+Dean%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22male%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22actor%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A42%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D5OIiZLo50Hc%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-24+12%3A06%3A53%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2256%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A27%3A%22resized_Eric_Dean_web_1.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A1%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2253%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22Matthew%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22Holbrook%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22male%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22actor%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A42%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZBJPV2YnXvk%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-24+09%3A40%3A38%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2230%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A28%3A%22resized_Matthew_Holbrook.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A2%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2254%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Steve%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22Murphy%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22male%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22actor%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-18+10%3A06%3A43%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2245%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A24%3A%22resized_Steve_Murphy.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A3%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2255%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22Anthony%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Berry%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22male%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22actor%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A42%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DGXB4_Q6oNUk%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-23+05%3A40%3A51%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2230%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A25%3A%22resized_Anthony_Berry.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A4%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2256%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22Emma%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Beard%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22female%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22actor%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A42%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DfUBF8L9pV1Q%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-23+05%3A41%3A45%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2228%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A28%3A%22resized_Emma_Beard_web_1.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A5%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2257%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22John-Henry%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22Carter%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22male%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22actor%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-23+05%3A42%3A19%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2234%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A35%3A%22resized_John_Carter_website_pic.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A6%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2258%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22Melanie%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Clare%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22female%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22actor%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-23+05%3A42%3A52%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2242%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22resized_images.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A7%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2259%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22Phoenix%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22Lee%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22male%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22presenter%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-24+09%3A15%3A08%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2231%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A36%3A%22resized_Phoenix_Lee_-_14.10_.04_.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A8%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2260%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Holly%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Bryan%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22female%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22presenter%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-24+09%3A30%3A32%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2223%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A29%3A%22resized_Holly_Bryan_web_1.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A9%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2261%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Susie%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22Juul%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22female%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22presenter%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-24+09%3A31%3A56%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2254%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A28%3A%22resized_Susie_Juul_web_1.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A10%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2262%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22Neil%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22Lumberg%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22male%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22presenter%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A42%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D7QDWDtm3tgs%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-24+09%3A32%3A34%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2227%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A30%3A%22resized_Neil_Lumberg_web_1.jpg%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22asset_size%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22large%22%3B%7Di%3A11%3Ba%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22candidate_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2263%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22first_name%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22Megan%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22surname%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22Roberts%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22gender%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22female%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22talent%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22presenter%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22availability%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22yes%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22youtube_showreel_1%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A23%3A%22youtube_showreel_desc_1%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22date_created%22%3Bs%3A19%3A%222011-11-24+09%3A33%3A16%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22age%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2214%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3B
```

Comment: "guess"? is this site for gamblers? I thought ist's for programmers.

Comment: Yes, guess. Because I can see that this is caused by the set-cookie, but since I don't have access to the code I can't be 100% sure. Someone needs to try it. Disagree with your -1

Comment: your guess what perfect, one optimized mysql query later we are cooking on guess again!

Comment: out of interest how did you find the size of the cookie?

Comment: "cooking on guess" indeed ;) Glad that it worked for you! To answer your question: From the error message I knew it was related to HTTP headers. I noticed your site (urbantalent) in the referer field and decided to open it in my browser. Then I ran search, captured the output - and noticed a huge cookie.

Comment: What did you use to capture the output? Charles? Firebug or something else?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, echo() the SQL statement (then die(), avoid to run into the error), and try it in a SQL tool, to see what happens. I think, it's a buggy SQL statement, or just the SQL engine does not like it for some reason - so you should try to get a detailed error message, instead of the "500 Internal Server error".

Comment: echo sql and run in PHPMYADMIN, and returns the rows expected.

Comment: change the SQL statement to a dead simple one, e.g. *select sum(dududu) from dadada*, to see wheter any SQL can run, or somehow the connection is failed

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to change this

```
if($type != "0") { $sql .= 'AND `candidates`.`talent` = '.$type; }
            if($age != "0") { $sql .= 'AND `candidates`.`playing_age` LIKE "%'.$age.'%"';}
            if($gender != false){ $sql .= 'AND `candidates`.`gender` = '.$gender; }
```

to

```
if($type != "0") { $sql .= ' AND `candidates`.`talent` = '.$type; }
            if($age != "0") { $sql .= ' AND `candidates`.`playing_age` LIKE "%'.$age.'%"';}
            if($gender != false){ $sql .= ' AND `candidates`.`gender` = '.$gender; }
```

Comment: might be that something with the access to the data returned by your changed query is wrong (at least the unprocessed data from the query is passed in to the tempate::build function).